# Building memory game minigame in JQuery (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a set of minigames for my major project, have being following a tutorial on the internet to make a memory game for one of them.

The code works up to where I generate a new board but the rest of the code doesn't seem to work. Have I done something wrong in my scipting? Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

This is my code for the memory minigame.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //speech
  var progress = 0;
  var txt;
  $('#complete, #speech').hide();

  function eventHandler() {
    switch (progress) {
      case 0:
        txt = "Complete";
        break;
      case 1:
        txt = "Move on the the next game";
        $('#speech').click(function() {
          window.location.href = "minigame4.html"; //next minigame
        });
        break;
    }
    progress++;
    $('#speech').html(txt);
  }

  $('#speech').click(eventHandler);

  // Memory Game //

  var memory_array = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'I', 'I', 'J', 'J', 'K', 'K', 'L', 'L'];
  var memory_values = [];
  var memory_tile_ids = [];
  var tiles_flipped = 0;

  //shuffle method
  Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function() {
    var i = this.length,
      j, temp;
    while (--i > 0) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      temp = this[j];
      this[j] = this[i];
      this[i] = temp;
    }
  }

  //generate new board
  function newBoard() {
    tiles_flipped = 0;
    var output = '';
    memory_array.memory_tile_shuffle();
    for (var i = 0; i < memory_array.length; i++) {
      output += '<div id="tile_' + i + '" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\'' + memory_array[i] + '\')" class="tiles"></div>';
    }
    $('#memory_board').html(output);
  }

  newBoard();

  //
  // all code works up to here

  function memoryFlipTile(tile, val) {
    // When tile is clicked, change colour to white along with its letter
    if (tile.html == "" && memory_values.length < 2) {
      tile.style.background = '#FFF';
      tile.html = val;
      // If no tiles are flipped
      if (memory_values.length == 0) {
        memory_values.push(val);
        memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
        // If one tile is already flipped
      } else if (memory_values.length == 1) {
        memory_values.push(val);
        memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
        // See if both tiles are a match
        if (memory_values[0] == memory_values[1]) {
          tiles_flipped += 2;
          // Clear both arrays
          memory_values = [];
          memory_tile_ids = [];
          // Check to see if the whole board is cleared
          // then display complete
          if (tiles_flipped == memory_array.length) {
            $("#complete").show(0, function() {
              eventHandler()
              $('#speech').show();
            });
          }
        } else {
          function flip2Back() {
            // Flip the 2 tiles back over
            var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
            var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
            tile_1.style.background - image = 'url(images/puzzle5/blank.png) no-repeat';
            tile_1.html = "";
            tile_2.style.background - image = 'url(images/puzzle5/blank.png) no-repeat';
            tile_2.html = "";
            // Clear both arrays
            memory_values = [];
            memory_tile_ids = [];
          }
          setTimeout(flip2Back, 700);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div#memory_board {
  padding: 24px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 456px;
  height: 300px;
}

div#memory_board div {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 28px;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(images/puzzle5/blank.png);
}

#complete {
  position: absolute;
  width: 105px;
  height: 25px;
  top: 240px;
  left: 289px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: white;
  z-index: 5;
}

#speech {
  position: absolute;
  width: 655px;
  height: 100px; 
  top: 330px;
  left: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: white;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MAS340</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    //javascript goes here
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="stage">
    <div id="memory_board"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from mentioned changes by some users, there are also other changes required in your script. As you are already using jQuery why don't utilize it fully?

Also have attached the event using jQuery like below as I suspect its able to see the function defined in the script while putting elements in dom. (Not sure about reason though yet)

I have changed your code in below fiddle. please check if its work for you (just corrected the syntax and replace some javascript code with jquery)

`$(document).on('click','.tiles',function(){
    memoryFlipTile($(this),$(this).data("memchar"))
})`

[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/6hn558ft/1/)

There is still a scope to optimize the code.

Comment: The tiles seem to increase size when they are clicked, how do I make them the same size?

Comment: This is because of the font-size set to 50px is css! check update and adjust height,width and padding as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in line 93 and 95. In addition, `html` should be `innerHTML`
Change

```
tile_1.style.background - image = 'url(images/puzzle5/blank.png) no-repeat';

tile_1.html = "";

tile_2.style.background - image = 'url(images/puzzle5/blank.png) no-repeat';

tile_2.html = "";
```

To

```
tile_1.style.['background-image'] = 'url(images/puzzle5/blank.png) no-repeat';

tile_1.innerHTML = "";

tile_2.style.['background-image'] = 'url(images/puzzle5/blank.png) no-repeat';

tile_2.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: There is no `html` property

Comment: It should be innerHTML instead of html

Comment: @charlietfl LOL I thought you were the asker, sorry man. And thanks

Comment: I changed all the necesary html = innerHTML and the tile_1.style.['background-image'] but still getting nothing